# Nginx html folder

Tags: nginx, users, directory

The files in the folder "/usr/share/nginx/html" belongs to the user "nginx" (or root ?), the primary user "2x2p1p" can't modify these files, then the best thing to do is:

1 - Change the user and the group of the folder "/usr/share/nginx/html" (chown -R 2x2p1p:2x2p1p /usr/share/nginx/html)

2 - Add the user "2x2p1p" to the group "nginx" (usermod -a -G nginx 2x2p1p; chmod -R 664 /usr/share/nginx/html)

So, what shall I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of these two options, the first is preferable.  By adding your user to the `nginx` group you may inadvertently give them access to other files critical to the proper running of nginx.  If you simply modify the permissions on `/usr/share/nginx/html`, you know exactly what you're exposing.